# overlay a sibling div which already overlays a parent div

Tags: html, css

How do you overlay a sibling div which already overlays a parent div? I have this `<div>` which resides in its parent div and overlays it perfectly. I want to overlay this div with yet another `<div>` (an action when someone selects the div). This overlay will be opaque, but I can't seem to get it to overlay for some reason. I've tried using `margin-top:-100%` but it won't do the trick. Any ideas?

```css
.one-third-text {
  width: 33.3333%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.text-btn-bg{
  background: #2ecc71;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text-btn { 
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .07s ease-out; 
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .07s ease-out; 
  -o-transition: -o-transform .07s ease-out; 
  transition: transform .07s ease-out;
}

h3.h3-text-btn { 
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.text-btn:active, .text-btn.text-btn-android { 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9, 0.80);
  transform: scale(0.90, 0.80);
  /*opacity: 0.80;*/
  color:#2ecc71;background:#f6f6f6; 
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="one-third-text">
  <div class="text-btn-bg animated-second bounceInUp">
    <div class="text-btn txt-btn2">
      <h3 class="h3-text-btn">Food &amp; Drinks</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- This div should overlay the above div -->
    <div class="text-btn txt-btn2" style="margin-top:-100%;">
      <h3 class="h3-text-btn">SELECTED</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Overlaying requires positioning...and I don't see any in your code.

Comment: give position absolute and then try to move that .